# Useragent override in Chrome Extension

Tags: testing, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, user-agent

I am building a chrome extension for helping test and debug a website. Is there any way to override the useragent override from within a chrome extension (shown below - image 1 is the manual way of doing this)?

[image: Chrome debugger user agent override]
I have also tried changing the headers by tapping into onBeforeSendHeaders but that doesn't work for some sites like twitter.com and maps.google.com
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem. I was missing "https://*/" under permissions in the manifest file.
The onBeforeSendHeaders example seems to work perfect!